# How does every subdomain of localhost point to localhost on Fedora?

Tags: fedora, dns

I went to configure my dns settings to point all subdomains of localhost (foo.localhost) to localhost but I found it was already working like this.

How is this done on Fedora? I don't believe the hosts file supports this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fedora (and recent versions of Ubuntu, for example) use [`systemd-resolved`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html) as the name resolver. For *any* name ending in `.localhost` (or in `.localhost.localdomain`), `systemd-resolved` will promptly return 127.0.0.1. It will also synthesize DNS records for the local hostname, and for the special name `gateway`; that is, for those names it won't query the configured DNS servers but rather return immediately with the appropriate address.